# append <li> to <ul> using JQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, html-lists

i am trying to create a nested **ul** by reading values from XML file. I am able to create first level **ul** but not able to add **li** elements under that. Firebug is not displaying any error. Please help code is given below;

```
$(function(){
    $.get("../XML/test.xml",processResult); 
});

function processResult(data){
    $(data).find("Category").each(showCategory);
}

function showCategory(){
    var catName = $(this).attr("Title");
    $("#menuList").append("<ul>" + catName + "</ul>");
    $(this).find("Function").each(showFunction);
}

function showFunction(){
    var funcName = $(this).attr("Title");
    $(this.parentNode).append("<li>" + funcName + "</li>");
}
```

Comment: Did the answer below answer your question? If so please mark it as the answer to help others in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are putting text directly inside a `<ul>` element, and using the wrong `this` variable. Try something like this:

```
$(function(){
    $.get("../XML/test.xml",processResult); 
});

function processResult(data){
    $(data).find("Category").each(showCategory);
}

function showCategory(){
    var catName = $(this).attr("Title");
    var parent = $("<ul></ul>");
    $(this).find("Function").each(function(){
      var funcName = $(this).attr("Title");
      parent.append("<li>" + funcName + "</li>");
    });
    $("#menuList").append(catName).append(parent);
}
```

Let me know if it works. If you have sample data available it will be easier to verify that it functions correctly.